# Is it possible to connect a .NET application directly to a Sybase SQL Anywhere db file

Tags: .net, database, oledb, sybase, sqlanywhere

I'm working on a .NET application to connect to an existing Sybase SQL anywhere database which is a .db file. Is it possible to connect it directly to the .db file just like how you would to an Access data file database or does it need a server to host the .db file just like MSSQL? If it is possible, how do I do it? Thank you very much :) I'm almost always using OLEDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The db file is not a normal readable file, and without the server installed, it can not be accessed.

The server is required to connect to the database, and to set up an client connections.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for
http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1054947

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply :) I actually read this before I posted my question. I tried the sample code without installing the Server software, just having the .db file. It always throws an exception that system is unable to start the server. This does mean that Sybase doesn't have the feature to connect to a database like Access right?

Comment: Oh well. Sybase is not your desktop database like MS Access. That I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's not possible to connect to the database without the server running. I tried it and it just doesn't work. It is possible to specify the location of the database provided you have Sybase server ready to run. Sybase will automatically run if you specify the location of the database. If Sybase server is not found, it should give you the error that says 'Server not found'. Thank you very much everyone :)

Comment: So pretty much what my answer says.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping it would be marked as the answer, but it's up to you.